# How do I use the "POST" method on an AJAX call in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I'm using the (free) Face++ API that's returns some good data based on uploaded pictures and/or picture URLs. I'm taking a class now that has introduced us to ajax calls using jQuery, but so far, we only use method: "GET"

**Can anyone help me understand HOW to use the "POST" method for an ajax call in jQuery?**

W3schools.com has demonstrated the call like this:

```
$.post(URL,data,callback);
```

However, I'm more accustomed to seeing the call made a little differently...perhaps like this:

```js
$.ajax({

  url: URL_request,
  method: "POST"

}).done(callback);
```

Face++ is asking that I pass it some information...
"api_key"
"face_tokens"
"landmark"
...and some other stuff that is specific to that API. My question is:

**Where/How do I pass that data to the site?**

...should the known information be passed as concatenations to the URL_request?
...is the known information hard coded in the object that's passed to ajax?

Comment: [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and then have a look at the examples on that page. Or under [jQuery’s Ajax-Related Methods](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/)

Comment: According to $.ajax documentation method is being used like this

    `$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: data,
      success: success,
      dataType: dataType
    });`

you can find more details [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'll want to check out the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post). There are a variety of examples that show you different ways to post data.

Back to your actual question: you DON'T want to add the extra data to the URL. This is known as the 'query string'. Query strings are useful for adding data to GET requests, but for a POST request, it's better to use the body. You can attach data to the body of a POST request like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: URL_request,
  method: "POST",
  data: { API_KEY: 'ABC123BBQ'}
}).done(callback);
```

Comment: Great stuff!

I've checked the documentation of Face++ to see what kind of information the request would be expecting:

[link](https://console.faceplusplus.com/documents/5679127)

I had some success in getting my initial trials to work using image URLs, but now I'm faced with a different challenge: this project requires use of the internal camera for a laptop; with the help of some code from another site, I can use the camera to take a photograph, but when I try to post that image using this AJAX call, it responds with a "400 Bad Request"

Docs provide clues, but I need more answers!!

Comment: That sounds like a different problem. File uploads have their own interesting challenges. You might want to post that as a separate question.